# Pagefile & outofmemory issues on Windows Server

Tags: windows, memory, windows-server-2016, pagefile, outofmemoryerror

We have a windows server machine with 160GB of physical memory running in a colocation that we use for data analysis. Most analysis are not very memory heavy but from time to time some users trigger queries that exceed the physical memory. As a result the system becomes unresponsive and the remote connections break.

Ideally, we would like to have this application be killed.
If I'm correct, it should not be possible to overcommit memory on windows systems. Thus I assume that when these events happen, windows is swapping like crazy and becomes unresponsive and remote connections break.
My questions are:

1. If we would disable the pagefile, would this mean that when the application requests too much memory it should get some sort of outofmemory error and potentialy die.
2. will the OS itself stay alive if a program fills the memory to the limit or will it crash?

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes.
2. The OS will stay alive but it may become unstable and crash ultimately.

What you need is a mechanism to restrict the application's memory usage. Have a look at this:
[limit the memory usage of a particular process on Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/1263090/is-it-possible-to-limit-the-memory-usage-of-a-particular-process-on-windows)